# Saving a list with SQL

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I have an Entry, A save button and a list view. when a user add an entry to this list how can I save this with  SQL so next time I come back to the app, the List is not resets. I have create a Model and a view model for this Job.

```
 public class Energys
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string EE {get; set;}
    }
```

and view model

```
class Viewmodel
    {
        public ICommand AddEnergyCommand => new Command(AddEnergy);
        public IList<Energys> energy { get; set; }

        public Viewmodel()
        {
            try
            {
              energy = new ObservableCollection<Energys>();
                energy.Add(new Energys { Id = 1, EE = "6 MV" });
                energy.Add(new Energys { Id = 2, EE = "10 MV" });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
               
        }
        public void AddEnergy()
        {
            energy.Add(new Energys { Id = 3, EE = "15 MV" });
        }
    }
```

I know working with Sql is not simple but ....

so how can I save all energys by AddEnergycomamnd for all time.

Comment: have you read any of the docs on using SQLite?  This should be fairly simple.  It would be best if you read the docs and attempted to do it yourself, then ask questions about any specific problems or errors you have.  As it is you are basically asking for the same information the docs provide.

Comment: it is not fairly simple if you  are Not writhing codes for decades like You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Store data in a local SQLite.NET database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows), if you want to insert data in sqlite database, you need to install **sqlite-net-pcl** by nuget package.

Then creating model, the `ID` property is marked with `PrimaryKey` and `AutoIncrement` attributes to ensure that each `Energys` instance in the SQLite.NET database will have a unique id provided by SQLite.NET.

```
 public class Energys
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EE { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, you need to connect sqlite database, and create table.

```
 public partial class Page4 : ContentPage
{
    public SQLiteConnection conn;
    public ICommand AddEnergyCommand => new Command(AddEnergy);
    public ICommand CreateEnergyCommand => new Command(CreateTable);
    private ObservableCollection<Energys> _energy;
    public ObservableCollection<Energys> energy
    {
        get { return _energy; }
        set
        {
            _energy = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("energy");
        }
    }
   
    public Page4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
        conn = GetSQLiteConnection();
        CreateTable();
        energy = new ObservableCollection<Energys>(conn.Table<Energys>().ToList());
      
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    public SQLiteConnection GetSQLiteConnection()
    {
        var fileName = "Energys.db";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(path);

        return connection;
    }

    private void AddEnergy()
    {
        Energys e = new Energys();
        e.EE = entry1.Text;
        var data = conn.Table<Energys>();
        var result = conn.Insert(e);
        if (result > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Added");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Already energy id Exist");
        }
        energy = new ObservableCollection<Energys>(conn.Table<Energys>().ToList());
       
        entry1.Text = "";
    }
    private void CreateTable()
    {
        conn.CreateTable<Energys>();
    }   
    
   
}

<StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="entry1" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                x:Name="btncreate"
                Command="{Binding CreateEnergyCommand}"
                Text="create table" />
            <Button
                x:Name="btnsave"
                Command="{Binding AddEnergyCommand}"
                Text="save data" />
        </StackLayout>

        <ListView HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding energy}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EE}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

**Update:**

About delete item from sqlite database, you can get ListView selected item, then delete this item from sqlite database.

```
  private Energys _selecteditem;
    public Energys selecteditem
    {
        get { return _selecteditem; }
        set
        {
            _selecteditem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selecteditem");
        }
    }
<ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding energy}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding selecteditem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EE}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                        </StackLayout>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

 public ICommand DeleteEnergyCommand => new Command(DeleteEnergy);


private void DeleteEnergy()
    {
        if(selecteditem!=null)
        {
            conn.Delete(selecteditem);
        }
        energy = new ObservableCollection<Energys>(conn.Table<Energys>().ToList());
    }
```

Comment: tanx alot. cherry i will try it and sent results.

Comment: @BehzadChangizi If you have any update, please share it here.

Comment: Hi. sorry for latency. it gives me the below error when I run it on my emulation.

Comment: energy = new ObservableCollection<Energys>(conn.Table<Energys>().ToList()); >>>>>>>>SQLite.SQLiteException: 'no such table: Energys'

Comment: @BehzadChangizi don't forget to create Energys table before getting data from table. I have created Energys table by `conn.CreateTable<Energys>()`

Comment: I know, but in your code  you initialize the  energy = new ObservableCollection  then u created table !

Comment: @BehzadChangizi Sorry, I have create Energys table to test before, I will update my code. My reply can solve your problem now?

Comment: I added conn.CreateTable<Energys>(); at initializing and the app works perfectly, Tanx very much man

Comment: If u have time can u help or address me to add a Delete Item button for this list ?

Comment: Yes sure, sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: @BehzadChangizi About delete item from sqlite database, you can take a look my update.

Comment: Thank you very much Cherry Bu, you are fast and awesome.

Comment: Cherry How can I recall this sq table in other xaml pages